# How to change text underline's line width in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, sass, user-experience

I want output as follows [image: I want to like this] btw currently I'm using bellow CSS to do this

```
.text-underline {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #f8f8f8;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
  }
```

But it applies to whole text are and I want to reduce width of this line

Comment: You'll want [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) for that.

Comment: a great article for that
https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple using a pseudo element:

```
.text-underline:after {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 5%; /* any width of your choice with any units e.g. px, em... */
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff0000;
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `pseudo-elements`, like this:

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

span::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Search Options</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have selected the entire item and need to use an element like span to isolate the "Search" part of your HTML

```html
<h1> <span class="text-underline"> Search </span> Options </h1>
```

Try that out